What is the durration of the Ultra Mini Turbos?
I asked this question for Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, but I'm curious about Mario Kart Tour.
What is the duration between regular Mini-Turbo, Super Mini-Turbo, Ultra Mini-Turbo, and Super Mushrooms? I'm actually thinking of downloading it some time soon, so I'll need the best speed strategy.

Assuming you are going straight on an even road the values are as follows:



Type
Duration at level 1
Duration at max level
Strength at level 1
Strength at max level




Mini-Turbo
0.333
0.666
1.05
1.15


Super Mini-Turbo
1.166
1.833
1.05
1.15


Ultra Mini-Turbo
2.000
3.000
1.05
1.15



This means that a Mini-Turbo is just as fast as a Ultra Mini-Turbo, however, the latter lasts longer.
Mushrooms are not dependent on the levels, so:



Type
Duration
Strength




Mushroom
2.000
1.20


Mushroom by bumping into someone
0.750
1.20



Duration is in seconds, boost is the percentage compared to the max speed.

Awesome, I love it. Welcome to Arqade, Pilzkopf. An upvote and your answer was accepted. What way to kick things off on Arqade, right?
